# IIS lista diretório ao invés de abrir a página

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

Criei um site no Visual Studio 2017, cliquei para publicar o mesmo e copiei os arquivos para a pasta do InetPub/wwwroot

Porém, ao invés da página ser exibida, a url está me retornando a lista de arquivos de dentro da pasta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como corrigir?

Segue meu web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />

  </system.webServer>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 518A8876-B620-4803-99F0-324F79C190B6-->
```

Configuração do IIS

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esta porta 88 esta correta? E você acabou de criar um projeto? Modificou algo?

Comment: Acredito que você precisa desabilitar a listagem de arquivos em diretórios: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b2f3d11-99c4-46b5-a92f-34af6909075b

Comment: acredito que você deve definir o documento padrão a ser aberto, veja o link: https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/defaultdocument

Comment: @CassioAlves a porta 88 está correta sim, eu quem escolhi ela, pois a 80 está ocupada

Comment: Poderia colocar o seu Web.config

Comment: boteoo web.config

Comment: @RovannLinhalis no tutorial que você me passou, pede pra indicar um arquivo default ou index para ser o padrão, mas no diretório eu não estou vendo esse arquivo

Comment: Qual deveria ser o arquivo a abrir o seu site? Qual foi a página inicial que você criou?

Comment: Possivelmente está dentro da para Views

Comment: @RovannLinhalis está sim, mas nao sei como deixá-lo padrão :/

Comment: @RovannLinhalis o site é em MVC, a página inicial é o controller Home e a View Index

Comment: então se você digitar `http://localhost:88/Home/` vai funcionar ?

Comment: Post uma imagem da tela do seu iis > Selecione o seu site e printa a tela

Comment: @TiagoS  print da tela = http://imgur.com/a/6xkXl

Comment: @RovannLinhalis se eu tentar localhost:88/Home, o erro é 
Erro HTTP 500.19 - Internal Server Error
A página solicitada não pode ser acessada porque os dados de configuração relacionados à página são inválidos.

Comment: aí já é questão de configuração, possivelmente no seu `.config`

Comment: A listagem da pagina é uma questão de segurança, o problema é que não existe nenhum tipo de arquivo na pasta que seja padrão para abertura, tipo um default.aspx. Os arquivos padrão para abertura do IIS são configurados por site. Isso é as.net mvc ou web forms?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O seu IIS está faltando alguns recursos necessário.

Para adicionar estes recursos:

Vá em **ativar e desativar serviço do windows**

Depois

- Serviços de Informações da Internet

  - Serviços da Word Wide Web
  - Recursos de Desenvolvimento de Aplicativos

Marque pelo menos os recursos que mostra na imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após isso é pra funcionar.

Answer (score 2):

Retire a linha:

```
<directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
```

Ou coloque false.

Comment: Aparece o erro:

Erro HTTP 403.14 - Forbidden
O servidor Web está configurado para não listar o conteúdo deste diretório.
Causas mais prováveis:
Um documento padrão não está configurado para a URL solicitada, e a pesquisa no diretório não está habilitada no servidor.

Comment: O IIS está rodando?

Comment: como faço pra saber?

Comment: Pesquise por IIS na busca do windows, e abra o gerenciador

Comment: está sim, confirmei agora

Comment: Você criou um site no IIS? poderia colocar um print de como estão os seus sites no IIS? E se você rodar diretamente pelo visual studio funciona?

Comment: Criei sim. De que tela do IIS você quer o print? No Visual Studio roda normal

Comment: Coloca da tela inicial, mostrando os sites

Comment: A resposta do @TiagoS provavelmente ira resolver o problema.